# HTML5 - FileAPI - writing files

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I am creating app in JavaScript and HTML5. I need to write data to a specific file, so I want to set path to file in code. It is not problem to do that with :

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
    console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
}
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024 /* 5MB */, onInitFs, errHandl);
```

But problem is, that it will invoke a security error, because `--allow-file-access-from-files` is not set for exe files. I don't want set it up hard for all pages. I would like to set that for only my page, the one that I am opening from local file system

For example it could be index.html:

```
C:\page\index.html.
```

Is there any way to do that?

I know just about manifest.json, but it will mean that I have to use distribute my app via the Chrome store. It is not acceptable for me, my project will not make any sense in that way.

Comment: why do you need to write to a specific file?

Comment: Because I need to create sth. like Tiddly Wiki. Page should by self-editable.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of FileAPI is to have a virtual sandboxed file system, not to manage OS file system. You can't edit some arbitrary file from user's drive, that would be a **huge** security hole.

What you probably want to do, is to **generate page dynamically**. As in example below, first content (html) is saved, then loaded and added to page:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
  console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);

  fs.root.getFile(FILE_NAME, {create: true}, function(fileEntry){
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fw){
      fw.onwriteend = function(e){ console.info('Write completed'); }
      fw.onerror = function(e){ console.log('Error:'+e.toString()); }

      var blobToWrite = new Blob(['<span>test</span>'], {type: 'text/plain'});
      fw.write(blobToWrite);
    }, null);

    console.log(fileEntry.toURL());
  }, null);

    fs.root.getFile(FILE_NAME, {}, function(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function(e) {
         var someDiv = document.createElement('div');
         someDiv.innerHTML = this.result;
         document.body.appendChild(someDiv);
       };

       reader.readAsText(file);
    }, null);

  }, null);
}
```

Hope that helps :)